# Criteria on a one-to-many relation

Tags: grails

My domain contains a one-to-many relationship like this:

class A {
    B b
}

class B {
    String name
}

I want to create a criteria query on A which will look for A to have the B object with the given name. It may return multiple entries. So... compare a given string with the "name" field from B and return the list of entries of type A for which B matches the name.

Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I am missing something that should be pretty easy:

```
def instanceList = A.withCriteria {
   b {
     eq('name','whatever')
   }
}
```

Comment: Indeed, solved, it was simple :) I thought I tried that. Thx!

Comment: Sometimes it just takes another set of eyes... Can you accept the answer when you get a chance?